# Add square to polygon composed of squares

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a collection of 1*1 polygons, each of which is defined by its boundary (a set of four points) and I use the function **area()** below in my code example to create these. I wish to combine such adjacent squares into a single polygon, with this polygon also defined in terms of its boundary points.

I wish to do this in a brute force fashion where I begin by adding two adjacent 1*1 squares to create a larger polygon using the function **join()** below and continue in this fashion in order to grow the polygon. So the first argument of join is the polygon so far and the second argument is an adjecent 1*1 square which I wish to add to the polygon. The return value is the boundary of the new polygon, **current** joined with the new 1*1.

Here's what I've come with so far:

```
def join(current, new):
    """ current is the polygon, new the 1*1 square being added to it"""
    return get_non_touching_part_of_boundary(current, new)  + get_non_touching_part_of_boundary(new, current)

def get_non_touching_part_of_boundary(this, other):
    for i,point in enumerate(this):
        if point not in other and this[i-1] in other:
            break # start of non touching boundary from a clockwise perspective
    non_touching_part_of_boundary = []
    for point in this[i:] + this[:i]:
        if not point in other:
            non_touching_part_of_boundary.append(point)
    return non_touching_part_of_boundary    

def area(point):
    """ boundary defined in a clockwise fashion """
    return [point,(point[0],point[1]+1),(point[0]+1,point[1]+1),(point[0]+1,point[1])]

a = area((0,1))            # a assigned a 1*1 polygon
a = join(a, area((0,2)))   # a assigned a 2*1 polygon
a = join(a, area((1,2)))    
a = join(a, area((2,2)))    
a = join(a, area((2,1)))    
a = join(a, area((2,0)))    

print(a)
```

This gives me the following polygon shape (with the numbers representing the order in which which its composing squares are added):

```
234
1 5
  6
```

The printed output of the code above gives:

```
[(2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 3), (3, 3), (3, 0), (2, 0)]
```

this is the minimum number of points required to defined the boundary of the polygon.

But if I add one more square to this shape via **a = join(a, area((1,0)))** and thereby creating a hole, my algorithm falls to pieces:

```
234
1 5
 76
```

Here's another polygon that my algorithm can't handle:

```
123
 64
  5
```

Can anyone help me? I'd like the holes in the polygon to be listed in a separate list.

Thank!

Comment: It is hard to understand from your description what is the input and what is the desired output. Please, clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your algorithm is hard to fix. Consider that for example adding a single square to a polygon could create several holes:

```
  xxx
  x x
xxx xxx
x  y  x
xxx xxx
  x x
  xxx
```

imagine for example that all the `x` are the "current polygon" and you then andd `y`...

In general a closed area is defined by a collection of closed loops and you can use just a single list only with a much more complex approach of creating zero-area bridges between the loops. A simple approach to what seems to me you are looking for is radically different:

1. loop on every square and for each one:
2. if the square is in and the square to the left is out (or vice versa) then you know you need a wall on the left
3. if the square is in and the square above is out (or vice versa) then you know that you need a wall above
4. collect all the edges in a dictionary where for every coordinate pair you keep a list of all walls starting or arriving at that edge
5. once the scan is finished you can rebuild the resulting loops by starting with any wall and keeping following the chain until you get back to the initial point... in case that when you arrive at a point there are multiple choiches about which wall to use for continue the walk then pick any of them.

if you collected the data properly and assuming you can add a border of one "out" cell around your data then it's guaranteed that you will get as result a list of zero or more closed loops because each point will list an even number of walls.

Those loops (when considering an odd-even filling rule) will be defining your initial area. Note that you may get self-intersecting loops... if you want to avoid that the algorithm is slightly more complex.

This approach is also much faster than processing boundaries one at a time and doing all those merge operations and the result will be general (including non-connected areas and holes).

## EDIT

The following image is the result of [a complete implementation of this algorithm](http://raksy.dyndns.org/cycle_collection.py) including a right-turn logic during cycle collection to avoid self-intersecting cycles. Different colors have been assigned to output polygons and corners have been cut to make the turns evident.

[image: output of the cycle collection algorithm]

Comment: How do I avoid self intercecting loops?

Comment: To avoid self-intersecting loops (actually to avoid any intersection even between different loops) you can just do the traversal by using a fixed turn pattern: if you can turn right at a vertex then turn right, else if you can go straight then go straight and only turn left if there are no other choices. An easy way to implement this logic without many nested `if`s is numbering the four adjacent vertexs (e.g. 0=up,1=left,2=right,3=bottom) and then building a 4x3 table so that when e.g. coming from vertex 3 you need to check if there are bridges to vertex 2,0,1 in this order (`tab[3]=[2,0,1]`)

Comment: Thanks Jan, I was thinking along these lines also.

Comment: @Baz: No problem... but Jan stands for January... the nick is 6502 :-)

Comment: Jan is actually a Swedish name :) I can't get the right turn rule to work. I get this intersecting polygon [(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2)] when beginning with the edge ((1, 2), (1,1)) So as my polygon grows it becomes an S, then a 9, then an 8, in terms of its shape.

Comment: Thanks 6502! Its your trick with corner cutting that I was missing. I thinking I also have another way of solving this problem. Instead you only keep the edges leaving a point in a dictionary (I use default_dict(list)). Then outer polygons are clockwise in direction and holes are anti-clockwise. So you use the right turning rule with outer polygons and the left turning rule for holes. To know if your working with a hole or not you can simply begin at a corner, not a junction. Holes have corners that go from down to right.

Comment: Awesome work 6502. I've written a C# version of this if anyone's interested: https://gist.github.com/2652112